# How to convert from utf8 to iso-8859-1 in perl

Tags: perl, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

How can I convert a string from `utf-8` to `iso-8859-1` in perl?

I am grabbing some `HTML` from a webpage which is in `utf-8`.  But I need to manipulate it into new `HTML` in `iso-8859-1`.

Answer (score 3):

```
use Encode;
$str = Encode::encode("ISO-8859-1", $str);
```